# Big Inserts into MSSQL Database doesnt work PDO

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I've got a problem which only occurs when I try to insert more then ~800 rows (each row 6 fields).

I am using PDO to insert into a remote hosted `MSSQL` Database and I guess there is something to big when I try to load such a big amounts into my Database. I tried to add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` into my `.php` file but it doesnt show me any errors.

**This is my Code:**

```
// Divide the textarea by line into a string array
$accounts = explode(PHP_EOL, $_POST['accountData']);

// Prepare the Query
$query = "INSERT INTO accounts (username, password, referral, dateCreated,region,idOrder) VALUES ";
// Create the multiple value placeholder
$qPart = array_fill(0, sizeof($accounts), "(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$query .= implode(",",$qPart);
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
$idOrder=100;


switch($priority)
{

    case("low"):
        $date="2050-01-01 00:00:00.000";
        $i=1;
        foreach($accounts as $item){
            list($user, $pass) = explode("|", $item);
            echo $user . ":" . $pass . "<br>";
            $stmt->bindValue($i++, $user);
            $stmt->bindValue($i++, $pass);
            $stmt->bindValue($i++, $refid);
            $stmt->bindValue($i++, $date);
            $stmt->bindValue($i++, $region);
            $stmt->bindValue($i++, $idOrder);
        }
    break;
    $stmt->execute();
```

What might be the reason for this and how can I solve this so I will be able to insert more than 800 accounts (user|pass) which I got from a textbox.

Regards

Comment: Are you supposed to be resetting your `$i` after the loop otherwise the count will keep going. Don't you want it to repeat `$stmt->bindValue(1, $user); $stmt->bindValue(2, $user);` up to 6, then start back at 1 on the next loop? Maybe not...that part is throwing me for a loop a bit...(no pun intended). I've never bound values like that.

Comment: Hey, yeah thats indeed a bit tricky part in my eyes but I got this from other stackoverflow questions regarding "How to insert multiple values in a one time query". Therefore I create a Prepare Query which offers multiple Values like 'Insert into accounts (username,password) VALUES (?,?),(?,?),(?,?)' and so on. I count on this $i to insert the NEXT username:password couple.